# Tampering detection by using sobel edge in processing

Tags: processing

I have to use Sobel edge detection to detect how an image has been tampered with. I have been able to implement the edge filter, but have not been able to figure out how to use it to detect tampering. I want to show the tampering by highlighting the region that has been tampered with in another color.

Can someone help please?

```js
PImage img, edgeImg;

int[][] sobelx = { { -1, -2, -1 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 2, 1 } };

int[][] sobely = { { -1, 0, 1 }, { -2, 0, 2 }, { -1, 0, 1 } };

void setup() {
    img = loadImage("face1.jpg");
    size(img.width, img.height);
    edgeImg = createImage(img.width, img.height, RGB);
}

void draw() {
    image(img, 0, 0);
    int matrixsize = 3;
    loadPixels();
    img.loadPixels();
    int loc = 0;

    for (int x = 1; x < img.width - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < img.height - 1; y++) {
            loc = x + y * img.width;
            int sx = convolution(x, y, sobelx, matrixsize, img);
            int sy = convolution(x, y, sobely, matrixsize, img);
            int sum = abs(sy) + abs(sx);
            sum = constrain(sum, 0, 255);
            edgeImg.pixels[loc] = sum;
        }
    }

    edgeImg.updatePixels();
    image(edgeImg, 0, 0);
    filter(THRESHOLD, 0.8);
}

int convolution(int x, int y, int [][] mat, int matrixsize, PImage img) {
    float rtotal = 0.0;
    float gtotal = 0.0;
    float btotal = 0.0;
    int total = 0;

    int offset = matrixsize/2;

    for(int i=0; i<matrixsize; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<matrixsize; j++) {

            int xloc = x + i - offset;
            int yloc = y + j - offset;

            int loc = xloc + img.width*yloc;
            loc = constrain(loc,0,img.pixels.length - 1);

            rtotal = rtotal + red(img.pixels[loc])*mat[i][j];
            gtotal = gtotal + green(img.pixels[loc])*mat[i][j];
            btotal = btotal + blue(img.pixels[loc])*mat[i][j];

            total = total + int(brightness(img.pixels[loc])*mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    rtotal = constrain(rtotal, 0, 255);
    gtotal = constrain(gtotal, 0, 255);
    btotal = constrain(btotal, 0, 255);  

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Using only Sobel edge detection, it would be very difficult to implement an accurate general image tampering detection algorithm. Is there any restriction on the way the image can be tampered with?

Comment: Maybe you can add images ground truth and tampered image, After that we can understand how it will works

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the algorithm can be used for your particular purpose, but I would guess you would need to run the same filter to the original image and compare the results.

```
PImage original = loadImage("face1.jpg");
PImage edgeImg;                             // previously created

original.loadPixels();
edgeImg.loadPixels();

for (int i=0; i<original.pixels.length; i++) {
  color origPx = original.pixels[i];
  color edgePx = edgeImg.pixels[i];

  // compare red values, since the edgeImg is B&W
  if ( (origPx >> 16 & 0xFF) != (edgePx >> 16 & 0xFF) ) {
    // don't match? do something!
  }
}
```